# .net openfiledialog handle the OK dialog result but dont close dialog

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, openfiledialog

I am using `OpenFileDialog`. When the user selects files and clicks OK, I need to search the selected files, if or not they are selected before. If there is a file selected before, a message box will be shown and the user must go back to openfiledialog. For example, when the user gives a file name which is not exist, the dialog gives an warning message. I want to do exactly same thing.

Comment: the question is not clear enough. what do you want to accomplish exactly?

Comment: When the user selects files and click OK button, the files must be searched and if a file is selected before, the program must go back to the openfiledialog window. This process can be accomplish with for loop, but I want to ask if there is an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CheckFileExists` property in the `OpenFileDialog` object.

Comment: this property is also true, but it is not my need. I need to search if the user loaded the file before.